# Dictionary data getting cleared after adding?

Tags: c#

This is a simplified code, why is the all the `Tuple` List data in my dict Dictionary (except for the keys) being cleared when i call the `item.Clear()` method? I cannot put the item parameter in the for loop as this is part of a much more complicated nested loop

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, string>>>();
var item = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    item.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("key1", $"itemKey{i.ToString()}"));
    item.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("key2", $"itemKey{i.ToString()}"));
    item.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("key3", $"itemKey{i.ToString()}"));
    item.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("key4", $"itemKey{i.ToString()}"));
    dict.Add($"dictKey{i.ToString()}", item);
    item.Clear();
}
```

Comment: You're adding a reference to `item` to the dictionary, then clearing `item`.  Why not set `item` to a new reference instead?

Comment: You have 'item.Clear();' as the last operation in the loop. It clears the List. You might be missing the basic differences between Reference and Value types here. String is not a good teacher for those, as it is a reference type that intentionally behaves like a value type.

Comment: @Christopher No, string doesn't behave like a value type at all.  It behaves exactly like a reference type, because it *is* a reference type.  It doesn't behave like a value type in any way, because it's not a value type.

Comment: @Servy Then you have very wierd reference types, that always use value equality on top of reference equality.

Comment: @Christopher That's not weird at all.  It's very common for reference types to use the equality of the values, rather than the reference.  It's very rarely useful to have the default equality of a type be the references.  It's just that the framework can't make an effective value equality on it's own.  But you should be doing it yourself for any type that has any real shot at needing to be compared for equality at all, regardless of whether it's a value type or a reference type..

Comment: @Servy: "It's very common for reference types to use the equality of the values, rather than the reference." List? Tupel? Dictionary? SqlConnections? Form? Window? Every custom class where you did not override the comparision routines? I am pretty sure none of those *abundantly* common Reference types use Value Equality.

Comment: @Christopher Tuples *do* use value equality.  I've never seen anyone compare a list or dictionary by the reference.  Anyone I've ever seen needing to compare them for equality has wanted value equality, and been forced to make a custom comparer that compares their values.  That they don't compare values by default is a mistake in my opinion.  SqlConnections, forms, and windows, are pretty much never compared for equality at all, because they don't really have a sensible definition of equality to use, so they simply keep the default because it's never used.

Comment: @Servy Ah, so it is common because you *ignore* all teh cases where Value Equality and Inmutabiltiy are **not** used. Yes, with that definition it makes sense.

Comment: @Christopher I never said that *all* reference types use value equality, or that *all* value types are immutable.  I said it's common to use value equality with reference types, which it is.  It's also common for reference types to be immutable.  A reference type being immutable or using value semantic for equality doesn't make it a value type.  It's still a reference type, it behaves like a reference type, and not like a value type.  Equality and mutability are entirely independent from whether a type has value or reference semantics.

Comment: @Christopher In the same way that a reference type can compare the underlying values of the type for equality, or be immutable, a value type can *not* use the underlying values when comparing for equality, or be mutable.  Because, again, those two concepts are *independant* of value/reference semantics.

Comment: @Servy: " I said it's common to use value equality with reference types, which it is." Show me a project. Count how many reference Types are inmutable. Count how many reference types use value equality. Then I do the same. Then we can maybe figure out wich percentage your definition of *common* is.

Comment: @Christopher And what would that show?  It doesn't make `string` any more of a value type, or any less of a reference type?  Having said that, I'd be more than happy to compare the number of reference types that *are actually used for equality comparisons* that use their reference as their identity versus those using the values within the type for their identity.  I've almost never seen reference actually used as the identity for equality purposes.  It's only used by the `Equals` methods of types that *aren't actually compared for equality* because it's the default.

Comment: @Servy: "And what would that show?" That your definition, my definiton and the readers definition of 'Common' match? You know, a usefull contribution to this Idea Exchange Platform? Rather then you sound like you only can disagree as long as your definitions are ambigious?

Comment: @Christopher But that doesn't change whether `string` variables have reference or value semantics.  That I think the number of reference types that use equality semantics for equality is "common" doesn't change that they all still have reference semantics, and that variables of a value type have value semantics.  How a type defines equality is *irrelevant* to whether variables of that type are references or values.  Which of course was the point from the beginning.  I don't really care if you think that it's uncommon for a type to use their values for equality, as it's not the salient point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `dict.Add($"dictKey{i.ToString()}", item);` An object reference gets added to the dictionary. Because you are clearing the item list, The dictionary also gets cleared.

Modifying the code to `dict.Add($"dictKey{i.ToString()}", new List<Tuple<string, string>>(item));` will not clear entries from the dictionary as a copy of the list is added to the dictionary.